# How to deal with the required value which does not have a default value in Django model

Tags: django, django-1.7

The version of my Django is 1.7.

I have a model named `Booking`, it has a Boolean field named `is_departure`, which is used to describe the booking is departure or arrival.

```
class Booking(models.Model):
  ...
  is_departure = models.BooleanField()
  ...
```

When I migrate my app, it will return me a warning that `is_departure` does not have a default value.

However, I do not want to add a default value for `is_departure`. This is a required value and it needs to be filled by user. I do not want to use NullBooleanField neither, because `is_departure` should not be null.

Is there any good way to remove this warning?

Comment: Why not just set a default value of `False`? Will that adversely affect your business logic? My guess is no. Even if the end user needs to select the value, you can still default the value to `False`.

Comment: @Brandon OK, I just want to see whether there is a wiser way than setting default value to False.

Comment: Not really. If initially setting the value to `False` in some way affected your business logic, then you can always use a `NullBooleanField` and set the initial value to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, what will Django put as a value for all the **existing rows** that now have a `is_departure` value that according to you, cannot be null, you can't satisfy this constraint.

If you're still developing, then you can reset the DB and you can indeed use `BooleanField` without default (since there will be no existing rows violating this)

Otherwise, I'd make the migration put a `is_departure` value (true or false) on the existing rows, consistent with your business logic